# Is this the correct way to represent a playing card in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make code for a Texas Holdem program. Would the following work correctly to represent cards. Also, how would I make a deck object of 52 separate card objects?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Card {
    public static void main(String[] args){}
    Enum Suit = {Heart, Club, Diamond, Spade};
    int number;
    public Card(Enum Suit, int number)
        {
            this.Suit = Suit;
            this.number= number;

        }
    public int getnumber(){
        return this.number;
    }
    public Enum getSuit() {
        return Suit;
    }
    public String whatcard(){
        return(" you have a " + number + "of" + Suit);
    }


{

}}
```

Comment: Perfectly valid approach that you have. There's no defined standard for modelling cards you could conform to, I think. `Deck` could  e.g. look like `List<Card>` depending on your needs. But the rest is doubtful, you'd need a separate Object `Game` or so that contains all the rest, the decks and what not, and also `public static void main(String[] args){}`. It is strange if a single card has a main method. Also `Enum Suit` will have to be public.

Answer (score 0):

If `getnumber()` gets a number between one and 13 and `getSuit()` returns a suit, it's correct. You will although need to write the cards ***"jack"***, ***"queen"*** and ***"king"*** in a different way! Here's the code you can use, to return the right output!

```java
if (number == 11) {
   return(" you have a jack of " + Suit);
} else if (number == 12) }
   return(" you have a queen of " + Suit);
} else if (number == 13 {
   return(" you have a king of " + Suit);
} else {
   return(" you have a " + number + "of" + Suit);
}
```

Hope this helped!